# Sitecore Commerce Error: Fulfillment '{Id}' is not a fulfillment permitted for cart '{CartId}'

Tags: sitecore-commerce

I wanted to add a `digital delivery` shipping option. I did the following

- Added a Digital Delivery item (Fulfillment Option) in `/sitecore/Commerce/Commerce Control Panel/Shared Settings/Fulfillment Options` with Fulfillment Option Type set to `Digital Delivery`
- Added a Digital Delivery item (Fulfillment Method) under the above item.

I then tried to checkout with this new shipping method but got an error like such when calling method `Sitecore.Commerce.Services.Carts.CartServiceProvider.AddShippingInfo()` in the Sitecore storefront:

```
Fulfillment 'ba530d23-6ac6-4e09-b8ac-407ec21d83d3' is not a fulfillment permitted for cart 'Default2625c25c-a7f6-4c21-bd77-5e7a9fb5aeb8storefront'.
```

Any other configuration steps that I've missed? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Commerce role is not able to validate  this option. A couple of things, if you haven’t  tried
1. Cache should be cleared after making any changes in control panel. Cache of your shops or authoring role which ever is being used. 
2. I am not sure but if you change shared settings, you might have to sync the content back to Commerce. https://doc.sitecore.com/developers/91/sitecore-experience-commerce/en/synchronize-content-items.html

Answer (score 0):

Try to review your changes based on Sitecore Documentation:

[Walkthrough: Configuring fulfillment options](https://doc.sitecore.com/developers/92/sitecore-experience-commerce/en/walkthrough--configuring-fulfillment-options.html)

Do not forget to mark your SellableItem as Digital.

If you want to mark your product as digital, you need to add any tag to the product or product variant from list below:

- OnlineTraining
- OnlineLearning
- Subscription
- DigitalSubscription

My blog post about that: https://www.brimit.com/blog/sitecore-commerce-9-how-to-override-policy

Answer (score 0):

Are you fulfillment options set up correctly at the Storefront level?

[image]